# Solving recurrence relation on Wolflam alpha

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, recurrence, wolframalpha

How can we get the generating function of (Schröder Number(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchroederNumber.html)) from
[the recurrence relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brpw2.png)

by using only wolfram alpha ?
What do I need to input to the search engine?

Comment: This question probably belongs on Math Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica syntax for this is

```
RSolve[{s[n]==s[n-1]+Sum[s[k]s[n-1-k],{k,0,n-1}],s[0]==1},s[n],n]
```

and Mathematica can successfully solve that giving

```
{{s[n] -> Piecewise[{{1, n == 0}, {0, n == -1}, 
 {-DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {(-1 + \[FormalN])*
  \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (-3 - 6*\[FormalN])*\[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] +
  (2 + \[FormalN])*\[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][0] == 1,
  \[FormalY][1] == -3}]][1 + n]/2, n > 0}}, 0]}}
```

It might be possible to further simplify that result into something more understandable.

Sometimes WolframAlpha will accept the same notation as Mathematica, but in this case it claims that it cannot understand this. You might be able to fiddle with the notation and get it to understand and accept it, but that is questionable.

You can read the documentation page for Mathematica's `RSolve` here: [RsolveDocs](http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=Awr9DuRThctarpIACQxXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTByb2lvbXVuBGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzcg--/RV=2/RE=1523316179/RO=10/RU=http%3A%2F%2Freference.wolfram.com%2Flanguage%2Fref%2FRSolve.html/RK=2/RS=8pNFPB._3ng97kQni6fAlGW0QIc-)

And the documentation page for `DifferenceRoot` here [DifferenceRootDocs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html)

Comment: Thank you for your advice !